# css :hover does not work after jQuery css change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a few `<p class="first">`s for which I use css `:hover` to change the bg-color on hover:

```
<div id="row_1">
      <p class="first">first_1</p>
      <p class="first">first_2</p>
      <p class="first">first_3</p>
      <p class="first">first_4</p>
      <p class="first">first_5</p> 
</div>
```

and css:

```
.first:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;   
}
```

but what I am doing as well is fire a `.click()` every time `.first` gets clicked which sets the clicked one a different bg and the others a blue one:

```
$('.first').click(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ddd');
      $('.first').not(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

what I am confused about is, that after the jQuery function fired the `:hover` does not work anymore?

Does anyone know why? Does `:hover` not work anymore after the bg was changed?

Comment: Check your firebug (or other debug tool) to see what the order of precedence is after it's been clicked. The hover might lose priority over the last added background-color

Comment: @Aboba yeah true, it is cancelled by the blue. But how can I change that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Fd5UJ/)***

Using `.css('background-color','blue')` is going to set the `style` attribute on the element to `background-color:blue;` which is more specific than the css hover styling. That is why you do not see the background color change on hover any more.

A workaround for this would be to use class names for the css styling like this

```
.blueBg {
 background-color: blue;
}
.greyBg{
 background-color: #ddd;
}
```

And then add and remove those class names on click

```
$('.first').click(function() {
 $('.blueBg').removeClass('blueBg');
 $(this).addClass('greyBg');
 $('.first').not(this).addClass('blueBg');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the cascading part of Cascading style sheets.  When you add a style via jquery, it adds the style as an inline style which will supercede any styles declared in the head or externally.

What I would do is instead of changing the background colors. Create another style named `active` for the link.  And add/remove the class.  That way you won't be adding any inline styles.